# How can I assign a variable from a method that might return null?

Tags: java, freemarker

I have the following code where I assign the result of a Java method to a freemarker variable.

```
<#assign singleBenchmark = solverBenchmark.findSingleBenchmark(problemBenchmark)>
```

The problem is that return value of that Java method might `null`. And even though I check if that variable isn't `null`:

```
<#if !singleBenchmark??>
    <td></td>
<#else>
    <td>${singleBenchmark.score}</td>
</#if>
```

**It still crashes on the `<#assign ...>` line if that Java method returns `null`**, with this exception:

```
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Error on line 109, column 45 in index.html.ftl
solverBenchmark.findSingleBenchmark(problemBenchmark) is undefined.
It cannot be assigned to singleBenchmark
    at freemarker.core.Assignment.accept(Assignment.java:111)
```

How can I avoid this exception without having to call the `findSingleBenchmark` method multiple times in my ftl?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The normal way to handle unsafe APIs like this is with the `!` (bang) operator:

```
<#assign singleBenchmark = solverBenchmark.findSingleBenchmark(problemBenchmark)!>
```

This is detailed in [this section of the FreeMarker docs](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_missing) and [the reasoning is given here](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/app_faq.html#faq_picky_about_missing_vars).

---

If your snippet is the actual code, you may shorten it (significantly) to:

```
<td>${singleBenchmark.score!""}</td>
```